# jquery Validate second select box by value of first

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-validate

I have 2 select boxes (sometimes 3)

First one chooses main category
Second one subcategory
Third on sub-sub category, if available.

First one reads

```
<select id="select_1" name="select_1" depth="1" class="valid"><option value="0">Select      category</option><option value="1">For sale</option><option value="2">Vehicles</option>
```

if, e.g. Vehicles is selected, second one reads:

```
<select id="select_2" name="select_2" depth="2" class="valid"><option value="2">Select subcategory</option><option value="112">For Sale by Owner</option><option value="122">For Sale by Dealer / Agent</option></select>
```

which has subcategoris, third one would read:

```
<select id="select_3" name="select_3" depth="3" class="valid"><option value="112">Select subcategory</option><option value="113">Cars</option><option value="114">Car parts</option>....
```

I want the second / third dropdown become neccessary if there's a subcategory.

What am i doing wrong?

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "check_2", 
    function(value, element){
        return (value == $("#select_1").val());
    },
    "You must select a subcategory."
);

$("#select_2").rules("add", {check_2: true});
```

Comment: Problem solved, doing it this way now:    
    
    $("form[name=item]").validate({
            rules: {
    select_2: {
     required: true,
     check_2: true
    },

Comment: Please do not post your solution as a comment!  Please post your solution below as an answer and then accept it as soon as the system allows.  This is the best way to help the community.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you simply forgot to show your call to `.validate()` or if you never called `.validate()` in the first place.  In other words, did you forget to call `.validate()` entirely or did you just forget to assign the `check_2` rule within `.validate()`?

Comment: Hey, i've tries to post my solution as an answer, but that's not possible because i don't have enough reputation! :(

Comment: I'm calling the .validate elsewhere, that's why i've tried rules add which didn't work... I've now put the new rule in the same file i'm doing the other validation and it bow works like a charm!

Comment: I guess you need 15 rep to answer your own question.  Please come back later and do so as soon as your rep permits.  Thanks!